# Is the Study of Random Numbers part of Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, cryptography, random

This might sound stupid but I am making an academic poster for my EPQ on the maths behind Cryptography (cryptology), focusing on number theory and was thinking of doing the maths behind one-time pad.  I haven't found many videos that help.  All I know is that the key is randomly generated and uses a $\oplus$ with the random key and the binary of the characters.  Would explaining the maths of random numbers be part of number theory.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: To my knowledge, no. Although, I did recently happen to see these two (very technical) papers which have elements of number theory, but are principally probabilistic https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.2034.pdf https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.03811.pdf.

Comment: I think the deal is essentially that, once you dig deep, the bodies of theory on which number theory and probability theory are grounded are largely disjoint (abstract algebra and measure theory, resp.). As a result, since one can rarely study more than one subject at a cutting edge level, people tend to be specialized in one or the other, but not both. That said, I'm sure that people exist who are experts in both subjects, and specialize in applications drawing from both fields.

Comment: "Everything is Number Theory." --Pal Erdos.

Comment: @B.Goddard ."God made the integers. The rest is the work of Man." -- (possibly) Dedekind.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet As far as I know, this was said by Kronecker.

Comment: @Peter. I was sure it was either K or D.